# Why is the echo not returning an ID after the SQL query in php?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have the following code in some php:

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM users where email = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
if($stmt->execute()){
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $isUserFound = $result->num_rows == 1;
    if(isUserFound){
        $row = $result->fetch_row();
        echo "<br>id: " . $row["id"];
}
```

I know that the user is found because the code inside the second if executes and I have done a manual check also to make sure. Is there something wrong with the syntax I have used? The echo returns just "id: " with no id from the database even though the user exists.

I have tried using single quotes for the id and also tried in capital letters, all return nothing.

Comment: Try `fetch_assoc()` instead of `fetch_row()`

Comment: that worked, if you post as answer will mark as such. Thanks for being so quick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php), `fetch_row()` is used to "get a result row as an enumerated array." This will result in an array like this:

```
$row = [
    0 => "2342",
    1 => "user@example.com",
    2 => "User",
];
```

Instead [use `fetch_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) which will "fetch a result row as an associative array" and give you something like this:

```
$row = [
    "id" => "2342",
    "email" => "user@example.com",
    "name" => "User",
];
```

Note that if you [enabled some error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/1255289) in your development environment you would have seen "undefined index" notices that might have helped you solve this issue.